# Launch another Android app from NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, native-code, launching-application

Is it possible to write C code using the android NDK which will launch another android app? (e.g. launch Google Chrome)

So far I've found only hints on how to do this for the Java SDK, not the NDK.

Comment: You can do it with JNI from native code. What do you mean by App - another Activity?

Comment: actually I just want to launch google chrome with some parameters from within my app.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have use Intents from the Java side of Android. All Android apps are running through Dalvik / Java side. As you are already using the Java side via a NativeActivity or a custom implementation, it shouldn't be too hard to setup a JNI call to fire off an Intent.

Comment: Is there any sample code which shows what you mean? It is my understanding that the JNI is used to have java code call android native c code. The question was if it is possible to launch external apps via c code, so why should I use JNI?
If, however, it is not possible to use c code to launch external apps, and it only goes via java/sdk, this would also answer my question.